# The type or namespace could not be found

Tags: visual-studio-2012, c#-2.0, msbuild-4.0

I'm currently trying to convert a WiX 3.5 custom actions project in Visual Studio 2008 to WiX 3.7 and Visual Studio 2012 and I'm getting the following exception:

> The type or namespace name 'MyNamespace' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The dll is definitely referenced and Visual Studio 2012 has no problem seeing the namespace.  Everything under the namespace even pops up in Intellisense, but when I build it I'm getting this exception.

Anyone have an idea of what's going on here?

**Additional Info:**

The namespace I'm referencing is a .Net 2.0 library and the custom actions project is a .Net 2.0 project.

**EDIT:**

After further investigation, I'm getting this warning, which I'm guessing is the root of the problem:

> The primary reference "MyNamespace, Version=8.5.1.20, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=f593502af6ee46ae, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not
>   be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET
>   Framework assembly "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0"
>   than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.

Why is it trying to use mscorelib 4.0 when this is a 2.0 project?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So it turned out that the dll being reference, while compiled to target the .Net 2.0 framework, was being compiled with the 4.0 compiler.  Switching the project to compile with the 3.5 compiler solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This may be completely unrelated but I had a similar issue yesterday. I had accidentally copied a class file (.cs) from one solution into another solution. Clearly, I hadn't added the references to the other solutions.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.”

Comment: I had this problem on Saturday and when reviewing the solution, a class had been copied into the wrong project meaning that there was a problem with references. So, it may not fix this persons specific problem but it is a valid solution and it may help some users.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, while the referenced dll was targeting .Net 4.0, it had its own reference to a .Net 4.5.2 dll. The referenced 4.0 framework target led us to believe that 4.5 or 4.5.1 were sufficient to handle things, but they weren't—the referencing project had to be 4.5.2 to handle the dll *and all its references*.

This was clearly an error on the part of the dll maker.