# The type or namespace name 'Google' could not be found

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, google-api-dotnet-client

Im trying to use Google.Apis in my WP8 project, but im unable to compile it. 
I got Google.Apis 1.8.1, and Google.Apis.Auth 1.8.1, and i can access it by IntelliSense, but, when i try to compile my project, i got this error;

Im using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone;

As you can see below, i got code-complete;

[image]

And i got the correct references

[image]

This is my final code, very simple class, only using Google.Apis;

[image]

And this error
[image]

Comment: How did you install the assemblies? Did you use nuget packetmanager?

Comment: Does this post solve your problem ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859942/the-type-or-namespace-could-not-be-found

Comment: After the compilation failed, have a look at the "Output" tab (next to the "Error List" tab in your screenshot). It may provide more information about the issue.

Comment: I used NuGet console to install the assemblies. And, since im using VS Express for Windows Phone, i cant use 'full .Net 4 framework'as my target framewoerk

Answer (score 2):

You should install the Google.Cloud.Language.V1 from *NuGet Package Manager* and then install the Google Cloud SDK for using the google apis in your project.

[image]

Comment: I have talked with some friends of mine that know much more about Visual Studio than i do and I decided to download Visual Studio Pro(was using visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone) and try to reproduce this error, and it worked well.