# Can Google cloud services work with Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to include Google speech api in my unity app.

I have followed all the steps in the api documentation for c# https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-csharp . I installed this package "Install-Package Google.Cloud.Speech.V1 -Pre" through NuGet package manager but no google references are being shown. This results to the error "The type or namespace name 'Google' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". I checked these possible duplicates but to no avail "[The type or namespace name 'Google' could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22482495/the-type-or-namespace-name-google-could-not-be-found)", "[The type or namespace could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859942/the-type-or-namespace-could-not-be-found)". Switching platform within unity from android to windows shows the google references but without resolving the error.

```
using Google.Cloud.Speech.V1;
using System;

namespace GoogleCloudSamples
{
public class SpeechGoogle
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var speech = SpeechClient.Create();
        var response = speech.Recognize(new RecognitionConfig()
        {
            Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
            SampleRateHertz = 16000,
            LanguageCode = "en",
        }, RecognitionAudio.FromFile("audio.raw"));
        foreach (var result in response.Results)
        {
            foreach (var alternative in result.Alternatives)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(alternative.Transcript);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The error occurs from the first code line "using Google.Cloud.Speech.V1;". Is it possible that unity cannot support google cloud services or am I missing a step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, we don't support Unity (or Xamarin) in any of the Google Cloud Client Libraries.

Our [supported platforms documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/guides/platforms.html). It's *possible* that the REST-based libraries *can* work on Unity, but we don't *support* that, and in particular the auth aspects are very likely to fail or require custom code.

To be clear, we'd *like* to support more platforms, but there's a pretty significant human cost involved in doing so, particularly for gRPC-based libraries where there's a native code component, and also particularly in terms of testing across a whole bunch of client platforms and Unity versions.